# Divide column by another column for a specific employee

Tags: sql-server, select

I have a table like this:

```
 [MS_EmployeeNumber]  [MS_Semel] [MS_Month] [MS_Amount]
      2222                400         1          20
      2222                154         1          40
      2222                 10         1          14
      2222               3000         1          120
      3333               400          1           20
      3333                154         1          232
      3333               3000         1          150
      4444                14          1          124
```

And I would like to create a table like this (without the calculation ofcourse)

```
[MS_EmployeeNumber] [MS_Semel] JanAmount FromBrutoJan   FebAmount ...
2222                   400         20       0.16=20/120
2222                   154         40       0.33=40/120
.
.
3333                   400         20       0.13 = 20/150  
3333                   3000        150       1=150/150
4444                    14         124          NA
```

I started writing this:

```
select
ROW_NUMBER()  OVER (ORDER BY  [MS_EmployeeNumber]) AS Row,
  [MS_EmployeeNumber],
  [MS_Semel],
  sum(case when [MS_Month] in (1) then [MS_Amount] else 0 end) as JanAmount,
   sum(case when [MS_Month] in (1) then [MS_Amount] else 0 end) /NULLIF((sum(case when [MS_Month] in (1) And [MS_Semel] = '3000' then [MS_Amount] else 0 end)),0) as SmlFromBruto,
  sum(case when [MS_Month] in (2) then [MS_Amount] else 0 end) as FebAmount,
  sum(case when [MS_Month] in (3) then [MS_Amount] else 0 end) as MarAmount,
  sum(case when [MS_Month] in (4) then [MS_Amount] else 0 end) as AprAmount,
  sum(case when [MS_Month] in (5) then [MS_Amount] else 0 end) as MayAmount,
  sum(case when [MS_Month] in (6) then [MS_Amount] else 0 end) as JuneAmount,
  sum(case when [MS_Month] in (7) then [MS_Amount] else 0 end) as JulAmount,
  sum(case when [MS_Month] in (8) then [MS_Amount] else 0 end) as AugAmount
from [dbo].[MonthlySalary] where [MS_MSF_Code] between 4 and 27 
group by MS_EmployeeNumber,MS_Semel
order by MS_EmployeeNumber, MS_Semel
```

I would really like your help to how to create a deviation column for each Employee & [MS_Semel] according to *his* Bruto [MS_Semel=3000], see example.
I the bruto is null set it to zero (see nullif), if not [MS_Semel] = 3000 for the employee not exsit set it to 'NA'.

Comment: Did you try using two queries: one contains only rows with MS_Semel = 3000 and the other query Returns only rows with MS_Semel <> 3000. So you can join these based on MS_EmployeeNumber and do the calculation.

Comment: You understood this question?   What's a "bruto"?